# how to create nested Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create new object by looping the data;

```
let a =[{"name":"test","age":12,"std":"1std"},{"name":"test2","age":14,"std":"2nd"}, {"name":"test3","age":11,"std":"3rd"}];
```

for my above array i am trying to get following output;

```
              {
                 "1":{"name":"test","age":"12"},
                 "2":{"name":"test2","age":"14"},
                 "3":{"name":"test3","age":"11"}
               }
```

below i am trying like this.please help to form above object using map();

```
             a.map(stu => {
                     stu.std={"name":stu.name,"age":stu.age} 
             })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Arrays are not `key:value`. Your desired result should be an object, not array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `std` property of each student to a nested object. You need to use the `stu.std` property as the key of a new object that holds the result.

```js
let a =[{"name":"test","age":12,"std":"1st"},{"name":"test2","age":14,"std":"2nd"}, {"name":"test3","age":11,"std":"3rd"}];

let result = {};

a.forEach(stu => result[stu.std.replace(/\D/g, '')] = {name: stu.name, age: stu.age});

console.log(result);
```

`stu.std.replace(/\D/g, '')` will remove the non-numeric characters of the `std` property to get the desired keys in the result.

Comment: thank you... actullay i am getting this errror message as "Arrow function should not return assignment"

Comment: That sounds like an eslint warning, not a JavaScript error. And it's inappropriate here, because `forEach()` doesn't use the return value, so it doesn't matter.